# Slide form on/off page and expand div

Tags: jquery, css, slide, slidetoggle

Ok this might be a little tricky but I'm sure it's doable. I have two buttons that I would like to trigger two forms with, initially the user would see the two buttons and one of the forms underneath, and when they click the other button a different form would slide in which is a little bigger than the first and expand the page/div to contain it. This is the HTML I have so far:

```
<a href="#" class="msg medlightgreen large-6 columns">send us a message</a> 
<a href="#" class="quote medlightgreen large-6 columns">request free quote</a>  

<div class="msgform">
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name">
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="monthly budget">
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="timeframe">
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
        <textarea placeholder="message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>  

<div class="quoteform">
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name">
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
        <textarea placeholder="message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

I tried adding the following to the JS but doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.msg').click(function() {
$(".msgform").slideToggle(200);
  });
  $('.quote').click(function() {
$(".quoteform").slideToggle(200);
  });
 });
```

[image]

Comment: do you have the jQuery includes? You probably do, just making sure though first

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm using Foundation 4 and I think it includes both jQuery and Zepto which is it's own library I think.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me so far:
I've created a jsFiddle:

**updated** http://jsfiddle.net/h9Zt4/1/

And also I set the style of the second form to `display:none`, since you only wanted one to be displayed at first.

so you will see

```
<div class="quoteform" style="display: none;">
```

This is so that the second form is hidden at first. Of course, you can also add "display: none" to the class css style.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: It jumps to the top of the page when I try it in the page I'm working on and I get the following error in Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slideToggle'

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean by "it jumps to the top of the page"? Does it work in the jsFiddle for you though? Just to be safe and sure, try including this jQuery include inside the <head></head> of your html document: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>